# how to handle jqvmap undefined values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

I am using `jqvmap` to show a map series `(ifthq.com scroll low left)`.  On the USA map, I have two states with values: LA and OH, both equal to 1.

The JSON used to feed jqvmap is: `{"OH":1,"LA":1}`.

The map shows, but does not fill correctly.  My assumption is that linear normalizeFunction would result in two states at max, and the rest at min.  This is not the case.

Since the US Map is over `50 elements`, and the data is only two, how do I set "default" data to zero in the `jqvmap`?  In other words, `undefined states would be equal to zero?`

Thanks.

UPDATE #1:  Code for question:
View definition.  mbrmap is the result of the data pull:

```
@login_required
def index_view(request):
    enlisted = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("E").active().count()
    officer = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("O").active().count()
    civilian = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("C").active().count()
    lifer = models.Subscription.objects.lifer().active().count()
    subscriptions = models.Subscription.objects.all().order_by("-Modified")
    mbrcnt = models.Member.objects.values('State').annotate(c=Count('State')).exclude(State='')
    mbrcnt2 = models.Member.objects.values('Country').annotate(c=Count('Country')).exclude(Country='')
    mbrmap = dict([(type_and_count['State'], type_and_count['c']) for type_and_count in mbrcnt])
    mbrmap2 = dict([(type_and_count['Country'], type_and_count['c']) for type_and_count in mbrcnt2])
    mbrmap.update(mbrmap2)
    units = models.Unit.objects.values('Unit_name', 'Hull_type', 'Hull_number').annotate(c=Count('memberunit__Member'))
    context = {'mbrmap': mbrmap, 'enlisted': enlisted, 'officer': officer, 'civilian': civilian, 'lifer': lifer, 'units': units, 'Subscriptions': subscriptions}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

html:

```
<div class="portlet-body">
    <div id="region_statistics_loading">
        <img src="{% static "img/loading.gif" %}" alt="loading"/>
    </div>
    <div id="region_statistics_content" class="display-none">
        <div class="btn-toolbar margin-bottom-10">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-circle" data-toggle="buttons">
                <a href="" class="btn grey-salsa btn-sm active">
                Members </a>
                <a href="" class="btn grey-salsa btn-sm">
                Units </a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-circle grey-salsa btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
                Select Region <span class="fa fa-angle-down">
                </span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" id="regional_stat_world">
                        World </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" id="regional_stat_usa">
                        USA </a>
                    </li>
                    {% comment %}<li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" id="regional_stat_europe">
                        Europe </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" id="regional_stat_russia">
                        Russia </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" id="regional_stat_germany">
                        Germany </a>
                    </li>{% endcomment %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="vmap_world" class="vmaps display-none">
        </div>
        <div id="vmap_usa" class="vmaps display-none">
        </div>
        {% comment %}<div id="vmap_europe" class="vmaps display-none">
        </div>
        <div id="vmap_russia" class="vmaps display-none">
        </div>
        <div id="vmap_germany" class="vmaps display-none">
        </div>{% endcomment %}
    </div>
</div>
<!-- PAGE LEVEL SPELLS -->
{% block PageSpells %}
    <!-- PLUGINS -->
    <script src="{% static "plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static "plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.russia.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static "plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static "plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.europe.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static "plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.germany.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static "plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static "plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/data/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- SPELLS -->
    <script src="{% static "js/index.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static "plugins/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}

<!-- PAGE JQUERY -->
{% block Jquery %}
    var mapdata = {{ mbrmap|safe }};
    Index.init();
    Index.initCmdSelect();
    Index.initJQVMAP(mapdata); // init index page's custom scripts
{% endblock %}
```

javascript code:

```
initJQVMAP: function (mapdata) {
    if (!jQuery().vectorMap) {
        return;
    }

    var showMap = function (name) {
        jQuery('.vmaps').hide();
        jQuery('#vmap_' + name).show();
    }

    var setMap = function (name) {
        var data = {
            map: 'world_en',
            backgroundColor: null,
            borderColor: '#333333',
            borderOpacity: 0.5,
            borderWidth: 1,
            color: '#c6c6c6',
            enableZoom: true,
            hoverColor: '#c9dfaf',
            hoverOpacity: null,
            values: mapdata,
            normalizeFunction: 'linear',
            scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
            selectedColor: '#c9dfaf',
            selectedRegion: null,
            showTooltip: true,
            onLabelShow: function (event, label, code) {

            },
            onRegionOver: function (event, code) {
                if (code == 'ca') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            },
            onRegionClick: function (element, code, region) {
                if (typeof mapdata[code.toUpperCase()] === 'undefined') {
                    var sval = 0;
                } else {
                    var sval = mapdata[code.toUpperCase()]
                }
                var message = 'You clicked "' + region + '" which has the code: ' + code.toUpperCase() + ' and value:  ' + sval;
                alert(message);
            }
        };

        data.map = name + '_en';
        var map = jQuery('#vmap_' + name);
        if (!map) {
            return;
        }
        map.width(map.parent().parent().width());
        map.show();
        map.vectorMap(data);
        map.hide();
    }

    setMap("world");
    setMap("usa");
    //setMap("europe");
    //setMap("russia");
    //setMap("germany");
    showMap("world");

    jQuery('#regional_stat_world').click(function () {
        showMap("world");
    });

    jQuery('#regional_stat_usa').click(function () {
        showMap("usa");
    });

    jQuery('#regional_stat_europe').click(function () {
        showMap("europe");
    });
    jQuery('#regional_stat_russia').click(function () {
        showMap("russia");
    });
    jQuery('#regional_stat_germany').click(function () {
        showMap("germany");
    });

    $('#region_statistics_loading').hide();
    $('#region_statistics_content').show();
},
```

Of note, the `initJQVMAP` function is a method in the index object:

```
var Index = function() {....
```

It is initialized by the `Index.initJQVMAP(mapdata);` function call.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: Thank you very much for attending to this this for me.

Comment: I believe the problem here is in the javascript.  in case you are not familiar with django.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Fill the JSON with all other states and `0` value?

Comment: well, what I'm actually hoping is that jqvmap will assume 0 when there's no value.  Otherwise, I'll have to reset my data models to have a table filled with zeros.

Comment: in this case, I only have two entities with values.  This is because I only have two records that count in my database.

Comment: I can't find documentation about `values` option. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: according to the instructions, the two values: normalizefunction and scaleColors, is designed to "heatmap" the area.  for example, the higher values are closer to the right color in scaleColors.  The problem here is that this is not competing 0 vs 1.  It's competing undefined vs. 1, because there are no other states with values.  therefore, normalizefunction is only competing against 1 and itself.  ergo, no color.

Comment: What exactly do you want to become `0`?

Comment: @arcee123, In that case I believe the first code on my answer might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the colors after creating the map:

```
var newData = {};
for (var key in mapdata)
    newData[key.toLowerCase()] = '#0071A4';
map.vectorMap('set', 'colors', newData);
```

[Here there is a working sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpGgEy).

**Edit**

I've also found this different solution:

```
var arrStates = [];
for (var key in mapdata)
    arrStates.push(key);
map.vectorMap('set', 'colors', arrStates, '#0071A4');
```

Comment: Hi Diego, thank you very much for this solution.  Is there anyway to re-integrate the `scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],` back into this movement, so the colors are varied?  right now, the values are 1 and 0, but what happens if you have `{'OH':3, ''LA':1}`?  this would need to be two shades.  Thanks.

Comment: DIego, thank you so much.  I wish I could award more bounty.  While you did change colors, Rusty's solution worked as designed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.extend()` to combine two objects, overwriting the values of one if they exist in the other ([documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)). For example:

```
var mySmallData = {
  "OH": 1,
  "LA": 1
};
var DEFAULTS = {
  "OH": 0,
  "LA": 0,
  "WA": 0,
  "ID": 0,
  // etc.
};

var fullData = $.extend({}, DEFAULTS, mySmallData);
```

`fullData` would now contain:

```
{
  "OH": 1,
  "LA": 1,
  "WA": 0,
  "ID": 0
}
```

This way, you have one object that has all of your defaults and you never have to mess with it. Your sparse object can have as few data points as you want, and it will always get expanded to the full set of states.